# requireJs order plugin: can it exist in a different path than the require.js basePath?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

when using the order plugin require.js looks for it in   the given basePath/order.js

example:

```
require(
        {
            baseUrl: '/public/js/'
        },
        [
            'require',
            'order!http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.7/underscore-min.js',
            'order!http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.5.3/backbone-min.js',
            'order!http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js'
        ], 
        function (require) {
            require(['application'], function (app) {
                app.run();
            });
        }
    );
```

it looks for the order plugin in `http://url.com/public/js/order.js` could I somehow store it not in the root of my javascript folder?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can place your plugins anywhere you like and point to their paths when configuring RequireJS:

```
require({
    baseUrl: "/public/js/",
    paths: {
        order: "requirejs/plugins/order"
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this, wasn't immediately clear from the docs that it worked this way.

Comment: What about for plugins that gets automatically loaded like text plugin which gets loaded via text!... ?

Comment: @Marconi It's the same. The example for the `order` plugin above applies to `text` as well.