# Configure location of text.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, requirejs-text

I'm using requirejs with the text plugin. By default, requirejs assumes `text.js` lives in your `baseUrl`. However, I want to keep it somewhere else. Where/how/when do I need to configure requirejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use requirejs's [path config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths) for this. From the documentation:

> paths: path mappings for module names not found directly under baseUrl. The path settings are assumed to be relative to baseUrl, unless the paths setting starts with a "/" or has a URL protocol in it ("like http:").

So you could do something like this:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    "text": "/absolute/path/to/text.js"
  }
});
```

Then you can use `text` as a dependency in modules and require.js will know to look for the file in `/absolute/path/to/text.js`.

Comment: So plugins are configured using `paths` as well. Great—thanks!

Comment: Heh, I've never even worked with plugins, but basically AFAIK require.js treats all files equally. See e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363379/requirejs-order-plugin-can-it-exist-in-a-different-path-than-the-require-js-bas (a bit old but still true).

Answer (score 3):

To add to shioyama's answer, the `.js` in the `"/absolute/path/to/text.js"` is not necessary. It is appended when require.js checks the path:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    "text": "/absolute/path/to/text"
  }
});
```